# Ripple effect not working mdc-icon-toggle in material components

Tags: javascript, html, material-components

Just started with [material components](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/buttons/icon-toggle-buttons/). I am trying `mdc-icon-toggle`, the HTML code

```
<i class="mdc-icon-toggle material-icons" role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Add to favorites" tabindex="0"         
    data-toggle-on='{"label": "Remove from favorites", "content": "favorite"}'
    data-toggle-off='{"label": "Add to favorites", "content": "favorite_border"}' 
    data-mdc-auto-init="MDCIconToggle">
      favorite_border
 </i>
```

JS Code

```
const iconEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-icon-toggle');

iconEl.addEventListener('MDCIconToggle:change', ({detail}) => {
  alert(detail.isOn)
});
```

Basic functionality is working fine, I am able to listen to the event but the ripple effect is not working properly when I click on the icon there is shadow around the icon that never [image: goes away]. Am I missing something as this is with radio button too?

Answer (score 0):

I am studying MDC now.

Use this form to work better, put the javascript code at end of your BODY tag:

```
<i class="mdc-icon-toggle material-icons" role="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Add to favorites" tabindex="0"         
    data-toggle-on='{"label": "Remove from favorites", "content": "favorite"}'
    data-toggle-off='{"label": "Add to favorites", "content": "favorite_border"}'>
      favorite_border
 </i>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
      /* MDC Ripple for Toggle button */
      var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-icon-toggle');
      for (var i = 0, node; node = nodes[i]; i++) {
        mdc.iconToggle.MDCIconToggle.attachTo(node);
      }
})();
</script>
```